# Kernel panic on Ubuntu 21.10 AMDGPU

Tags: boot, kernel, amdgpu, 21.10

I'm trying to boot the latest Ubuntu 21.10 on Lenovo ThinkPad E14 (Ryzen 3 5300U with integrated Renoir graphics), and I'm stuck on Lenovo logo. When trying to boot with safe graphics, I got the following error:

```
drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
Kernel panic - not syncing: stack protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in:elantech_change_report_id+0x1bf/)x1c4 [psmouse]
CPU: 3 PID: 136 Comm: kworker/3:1 Not tainted 5.13.0-19-generic #19-Ubuntu
Hardware name: LENOVO 20Y7S00R00/20Y7S00R00, BIOS R10ET28W (1.07) 07/15/2021
Workqueue: events_log serio_handle_event
```

The complete stack trace is in the picture[image: stack trace]

I tried the `amdgpu.dc=0` on normal boot option but the error persisted. Note that the boot is successful on 20.04.3 and 21.04. What needs to be done for successful boot? This problem is not observed in NVIDIA card.

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5008 (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 164c (rev c3)
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
04:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
04:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
04:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
```

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:c123 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:5503 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix FingerPrint Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 30c9:003a 8SSC20F27145V1SR18H039A Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 24ae:2000 RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: If you're able to get to the GRUB menu, select the desired boot item, hit the "e" key to enter edit mode, find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", then control-x or F10 continue booting. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema nothing new happened with `nomodeset`. I still received the kernel panic.

Comment: See answer from @rainer

Comment: I had the same issue, kernel 5.11.0-38 seems to work for me (5.13.0.19.30 NOT).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1945590

See the above bug entry for more information. It is apparently a known problem. Booting older kernel instead as a workaround.

Comment: I checked the launchpad, tried turning off touchpad and trackpoint, and 21.10 did boot normally after that. Also that is a mainline kernel bug, not restricted to specific distro.

Comment: Finally it has been fixed since kernel 5.13.0-28.